# How to get persistent (permanent) smb mount using kerberos authentication on RHEL7?

Tags: linux, rhel, kerberos, smb

**Environment:** I have joined a few of my RHEL 7.3 boxes with MS AD domain using realmd/sssd. I have allowed only members of a few allowed groups can login to the box. Credentials caching is disabled. All works well without any problem.

**What I need to achieve next:** I want one Windows SMB share to be permanently mounted to the Linux (in the fstab or else) using Kerberos(passwordless).

**What I have achieved so far:** I am able to mount the Windows SMB path, but it expires when the manually generated TGT ticket expires.

**How I’m doing it:** I generate TGT ticket using ‘kinit’

then TGT ticket for cifs mount using kvnp

Then making an entry in the fstab with ‘sec=krb5’ and providing the uid of the desired service account.

Using the above the SMB share is mounted successfully but expires in 9 hours upon expiration of the TGT ticket.

Please suggest if there is something that I can do to make the mount permanent.

**Note:** I'm not modifying the TGT ticket expiration time thinking it may cause some security or compliance concerns.(please, correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks, duplicate text removed. I asked this question in StackExchange and was suggested to post here. And the copy/paste error happened.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using the same default principal name that is used in your cache you should be able to just create a reoccurring cronjob that runs kinit with your keytab assuming you already have one created and stored securely.